# Problems with connect to MongoDB Atlas from Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB Atlas and Python. I am using Python 3.9 and PyMongo 4.0.1: I have trouble connecting to a free MongoDB Atlas cluster that I have created based on MongoDB instruction. Please see the attached image -- https://behainguyen.files.wordpress.com/2022/01/cloud-mongo-db-connection-string.jpg, my connection string is:

```
mongodb+srv://behai:<password>@cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I have replaced  with the password for user "behai" in MongoDB Atlas. and I store it as MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING in my keys.py file.

I connect as:

```
import pymongo
import keys

client = pymongo.MongoClient( keys.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING )
```

And I have the error:

```
ConfigurationError: All nameservers failed to answer the query cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net. IN TXT: Server 192.168.0.1 UDP port 53 answered DNS message is malformed.
```

If I dropped "+srv" from the connection string, I could connect, but later accesses such as creating a database, creating a collection then inserting into the collection would result in an error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61d8d475109bbda8e8b938f0, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')>]>
```

When I try to ping cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net:

```
C:\>ping cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net
```

I would get this response:

```
Ping request could not find host cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net. Please check the name and try again.
```

Does it seem that host "**cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net**" does not exist?

But when I look into my MongoDB Atlas windows, I can see I have made 6 connections during the last 99 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `dnspython`/`pymongo[srv]` <- (includes the dnspython) using pip and add the srv extra back.

```
import pymongo
    
db = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://behai:<password>@cluster0.71o6u.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
```

Comment: I carried out your suggestion:

```
In [9]: pip install pymongo[srv]
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo[srv] in c:\users\behai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython<3.0.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\behai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pymongo[srv]) (2.1.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Despite that, I went ahead and re-ran the codes, I still have the error. 

Thank you for your helps. I do appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm go setting Project:YOURPROJECT and check if dnspython is there if not then click + icon and seach dnspython and install it.

When i tried to install on command line it keep saying its already installed but didnt work. This will probably solve your problem.